# Are HTTP sessions now shared across browsers

Tags: php, session, browser

When developing a PHP site I use Chrome as my primary browser. Typically I am logged in as an admin user. When I need to check out the site as a regular user (but retain access as admin) I open another browser (MS Edge) - I do this because opening the site in a new tab or window retains the session and I can only be one user at a time. Today I was logged in as admin in Chrome. I accessed the site in Edge and was immediately shown the admin page and was logged in as the admin user I was in Chrome. In Edge, I logged out and back in as a regular user. When I went back to Chrome I was now the regular user.

Are HTTP sessions now shared across browsers?

Comment: No they're not, I think something else must be going on.

Comment: It sounds like the site is using your IP to implement sessions. This is very unsafe design, since the same IP could be multiple computers behind a firewall or proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out both browsers had the same session ID and since they were stored in a cookie that did not expire for 24 hours they continued to stay the same until I cleared the cookie on Edge. It then got a new session ID and the behavior returned to normal. One in a billion?

Comment: Session IDs should be unique, that shouldn't happen. Very weird. As Barmar said above, are you sure your app doesn't allocate sessions based on IP address or something?